# Cascaded Insert Into Multiple Tables - Best Practice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables (Country, State and City) which on client creation populate a replica table using client id

Default Table

```
tbl_Country
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

tbl_State
public int Id { get; set; }
public int CountryId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

tbl_City
public int Id { get; set; }
public int StateId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Client Table

```
tbl_Client_Country
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ClientId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

tbl_Client_State
public int Id { get; set; }
public int CountryId { get; set; }
public int ClientId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

tbl_Client_City
public int Id { get; set; }
public int StateId { get; set; }
public int ClientId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The insert script suppose to start with a loop using :

```
var countries = from x in _context.tbl_Country select x;
```

like:

```
foreach(var country in countries){

//insert country and return key for state insert

//select all state using country.Id

 foreach(var state in states){

 //insert state and return key for city insert

 //select all city using state.Id

 foreach(var city in cities){

 }


 }

}
```

I have looked at questions with related titles but this case is different.

Question: Is there a more efficient way to do this without cascading.

Comment: If you create a Client, why not just identify his `City` by `CityId` and nothing else. Because you identified the `City`, you also identified the `State` and the `Country`, haven't you?

Comment: I don't think you read the question @HaraldCoppoolse

Comment: During client creation, I want to move data from the original location table to client location table using client Id